# Rails form input fields not saving to DB (but created_at timestamp is)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

I am new to rails and trying to understand why my form doesnt't get saved to the database. This might be a consequence of me not fully grasping the MVC framework of rails so hopefully once I figure this out it will provide clarity.

The update time saves but the remaining records show up as null. Outside of my submit button (triggering update and create timestamps) there doesnt seem to be interaction between the database and my form.

Here is my controller:

```
  def create
  @recommendation=Recommendation.new
  end
```

Here is my form:

```
<%= form_for @recommendation, url: {action: "create"} do |f| %>
    <% if @recommendation.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
    <h2><%= pluralize(@recommendation.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this recommendation from being saved:</h2>
    <% end %> 

  <div><%= f.label "recommendation category"%><br />
  <%= f.text_field :rec_type %></div>

  <div><%= f.label "Description" %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :rec_description %></div>

  <div><%= f.label "Link" %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :link %></div>

  <div> <%= f.submit "Submit Recommendation" %></div>
<% end %>
```

Here is my log after submitting:

```
Started POST "/recommendations/create" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-25 00:42:39 -0500

Processing by RecommendationsController#create as HTML

  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"U2+h08nRXgkkNp0u74a5Gmh0eSWU4gP67A2CWGaJ/fE=", "recommendation"=>{"rec_type"=>"asdf", "rec_description"=>"efads", "link"=>"wfea"}, "commit"=>"Submit Recommendation"}

   (0.1ms)  begin transaction

  SQL (617.6ms)  INSERT INTO "recommendations" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?)  [["created_at", Wed, 25 Dec 2013 05:42:39 UTC +00:00], ["updated_at", Wed, 25 Dec 2013 05:42:39 UTC +00:00]]

   (1.6ms)  commit transaction
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the Model.new just create a instance of the associated class .it does not save it into the database .render your form through new action. also you do not have toput action create in form url . According to rails convention a model new instance always goes to its create method.it should be

```
def new
 @recommendation=Recommendation.new
end

def create
 @recommendation=Recommendation.new(allowed_params)
 @recommendation.save
end

private
def allowed_params
  params.require(:recommendation).permit(:rec_type, :rec_description, :link)
end
```